# In qgis2threejs html output select deselect the layers not working

Tags: qgis, dem, layers, viewshed, qgis2threejs

I used qgis2threejs to output 3d model with a dem and another viewshed output.
I want to tick untick the layers for displaying and not displaying the layer.But the select unselect option in right window of qgis2threejs in not displaying and hiding the layers.

I used additional DEM option to integrate the additional layer in the output with display type Map canvas image.

```
[![on selecting viewShed the viewShed layer in not appearing][1]][1]
```

I want to tick/untick that option to show/hide the layers in the 3d model.
I googled but could find the results.

I have created a model including that viewShed but the tick/untick option to hide/show the layer is the feature i want in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution...

1. Map Canvas and Layer Preparation

   - Hide viewshed analysis result from map canvas
   - Duplicate the elevation layer
2. Settings for Background Layer

   - Select the original elevation layer in main DEM panel
   - Choose `Map canvas image` in display type group box
3. Settings for Viewshed Analysis Result Layer

   - Check the copied elevation layer under additional DEM
   - Choose `Layer image` option in display type group box, click `Select layer` button and then check the viewshed analysis result layer in the Select layer dialog
   - Check `Transparent background` option
4. Export